# How to read multi line file with different number of columns in Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

My input looks like:

```
1234,9999232
342424,888922,true
45333,799999
```

Thats like `id_1, id_2, a_bool` where `a_bool` is optional.
The `FieldSetMapper` reads the tokens and sets the values in the model.
The line tokenization logic is as follows:

```
<bean id="inputLineTokenizers"
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer">
    <property name="tokenizers">
        <map>
            <entry key="*,*" value-ref="ID1_ID2_TOKENIZER"/>
            <entry key="*,*,*" value-ref="ID1_ID2_ABOOL_TOKENIZER"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="parentLineTokenizer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
    <property name="delimiter" value=","/>
</bean>
<bean id="ID1_ID2_TOKENIZER" parent="parentLineTokenizer">
    <property name="names" value="id1,id2"/>
</bean>
<bean id="ID1_ID2_ABOOL_TOKENIZER" parent="parentLineTokenizer">
    <property name="names" value="id1,id2,aBool"/>
</bean>
```

But the problem is with given file as on the top, it throws exception about the missing index for records where third parameter isn't present.

How do I solve it? By checking if third index exists and then reading it in the `FieldSetMapper` or is there any other elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve it by setting `strict` to `false` using the `DelimitedLineTokenizer` only.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
    <property name="names" value="ID1,ID2,A_BOOL"/>
    <property name="strict" value="false"/>
</bean>
```